# Possible Pivot in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to fetch the data from a DB to get number of Unused Applications for 60 days and 90 Days. I've tried the below:

```
SELECT 
Uname AS [User ID],
AppName As [Application],
COUNT(*) AS [Unused App for 60 Days]
FROM APPTABLE 
WHERE LAST_USE<getutcdate()-60 
GROUP BY Uname, AppNameNow
```

I want to do the same for 90 days as well but in this same query. I'm having difficulty in doing it.

Could you help me understand how to do it? Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation.  I would suggest using `dateadd()` to be explicit about the intention of the logic:

```
SELECT Uname AS [User ID], AppName As [Application],
       SUM(CASE WHEN LAST_USE < DATEADD(DAY, -60, getutcdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unused_60,
       SUM(CASE WHEN LAST_USE < DATEADD(DAY, -90, getutcdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unused_90
FROM APPTABLE 
WHERE LAST_USE < DATEADD(DAY, -60, getutcdate())
GROUP BY Uname, AppNameNow
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause is still filtering the dates.  But you need to be careful that the `WHERE` is consistent with the time frames in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

count(*) is logically equivalent to sum(1).

Instead, use a conditional case:

```
 sum(case when LAST_USE<getutcdate()-60 then 1 else 0 end) as [Unused App for 60 Days]
,sum(case when LAST_USE<getutcdate()-90 then 1 else 0 end) as [Unused App for 90 Days]
```

of course, include the larger set in your `where`

Comment: And `sum(case ... then 1 else 0 end)` is logically equivalent to `count(case ... then 1 end)`

Comment: Not really. Apart from using `distinct`, anything you put in the `count()` does the same.

Comment: You didn't read: `case when ... then 1 end` is the same as `case when ... then 1 else null end` and `count` only adds up non-nulls